# fetch() method send the default values instead the new ones

Tags: backbone.js

I have an issue with a model, i instanciate it up with some default values, i am using the `set()` method to change it, and when i use the `fetch()` méthod, i get the defaults values instead the new ones, i tried to log `myModel.toJSON()` in the console and i see the new values, i launch `myModel.fetch()` i get the defaults values on the server side, crazy no ?

Here is the model prototype:

```
window.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        id : "1",
        username : "anonymous",
        facebook_id : "1235486421",
        facebook_token : "AEZH93FZFEFSFSFS4545154sfsfSF"
    },
    urlRoot: 'http:/localhost:3000/user',
    initialize : function() {
        console.log('User Constructor...');
        this.url = "http://localhost:3000/user/"+this.get('username')+'/'+this.get('facebook_id')+'/'+this.get('facebook_token');
    }
});
```

Here is the chunck of code where i use `fetch()`:

```
    fetch_user: function(){
    var CurrentUser = new User();
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + ', id: '+response.id+', token: '+access_token);
                CurrentUser.set('username', response.name);
                CurrentUser.set('facebook_id', response.id);
                CurrentUser.set('facebook_token', access_token);
                console.log('Current user is:  ' + CurrentUser.toJSON());
                CurrentUser.fetch({
                    success: function(_model){
                        console.log('User fetched successfully');
                    },
                    error: function(_model, error){
                        console.log('User fetched unsuccessfully');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
},
```

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you need `save` instead of `fetch` ?

Comment: Why ? I don't want to save anything just get the whole datas from the facebook datas.

Comment: Man! Yu no change model.url at all after initialize. So how do you expect to get different results? Currentuser.url will not change automagically :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your URL scheme is not default "/object/id",  you should update URL:

```
window.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        id : "1",
        username : "anonymous",
        facebook_id : "1235486421",
        facebook_token : "AEZH93FZFEFSFSFS4545154sfsfSF"
    }, events {
        "change" : "updateUrl"
    },
    initialize : function() {
        console.log('User Constructor...');
        this.updateUrl();
    },
    updateUrl : function() {
        this.url = "http://localhost:3000/user/" +
                   this.get('username') +
                   '/'+this.get('facebook_id') + 
                   '/'+this.get('facebook_token');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone fetches based on whatever is set as the model's id attribute.  When you instantiate the new User, the id is set to 1 by default.  When you call fetch, Backbone attempts to fetch based on the urlRoot (since it is not part of a collection), and not the URL: 
http:/localhost:3000/user/1

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot

If you are looking to fetch based on some non-id attribute(s), you'll probably have to look into overriding Backbone's fetch.

Answer (score 0):

i wasted almost an hour over the same. All you need to take care is models get updated after the fetch success method,

```
 CurrentUser.fetch({
                success: function(_model){
                  console.log(_model);
 }
```